# Difference between "DROP COLUMN" and "DROP" keywords in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-drop

I just noticed you can write both in PostgreSQL. Is there any difference or is it just a "simplified" syntax. 
As far as I know, both of these does exactly the same.

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP my_column;
```

vs

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN my_column;
```

EDIT: I've searched around for this, but couldn't find anything. That includes the documentation.

Comment: have you checked the documentation?

Comment: @Watercolours I think you don't understand PostgreSQL Documentation, see my answer for details

Comment: I did read the docs, but missed the line that said it could be omitted. As well as the [] being optional. My bad. Anyways, going to leave the question here for others in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html), `COLUMN` is optional i.e. the statements are equivalent. Personally, I'd keep it for clarity

Answer (score 3):

Both syntax have same meaning,its your wish to choose among the two syntax, for the below example Keyword *COLUMN* can used for more clarity.

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN col1, 
                  DROP COLUMN col2, 
                  DROP COLUMN col3, 
                       .... 
                  DROP COLUMN col_n;
```

The document itself is described that the keyword *COLUMN* is optional, because
as per the documentation

```
ALTER TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] [ ONLY ] name [ * ]
    action [, ... ]
ALTER TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] [ ONLY ] name [ * ]
    RENAME [ COLUMN ] column_name TO new_column_name
ALTER TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] [ ONLY ] name [ * ]
    RENAME CONSTRAINT constraint_name TO new_constraint_name
ALTER TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] name
    RENAME TO new_name
ALTER TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] name
    SET SCHEMA new_schema
ALTER TABLE ALL IN TABLESPACE name [ OWNED BY role_name [, ... ] ]
    SET TABLESPACE new_tablespace [ NOWAIT ]

where action is one of:

    ADD [ COLUMN ] column_name data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ column_constraint [ ... ] ]
    DROP [ COLUMN ] [ IF EXISTS ] column_name [ RESTRICT | CASCADE ]
```

FYI, keywords written inside `[]` indicates **optional**

ex. `DROP [ COLUMN ]` here *COLUMN* is **optional**

Comment: yes the word inside `[]` are optional, but some of those optional words change the way the request is processed (eg: `IF EXISTS` )

Answer (score 2):

As decribed in [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-altertable.html), it can be omitted.

> The key word COLUMN is noise and can be omitted.